# JQuery input checkbox set class only if class is missing

Tags: jquery, input, addclass

I want to set class to Checkbox only if preexising class is missing for the checkbox. Also note it it may contain empty class then also overwrite it with new class.
I'm using following but how should I add the condition to the find?

```
$(this).find("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").addClass('IE8Border');
```

I'm trying in this direction:

```
$(this).find("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
    $(this)[("[class='']")].addClass('IE8Border');
    $(this)[(":not([class])")].addClass('IE8Border');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use hasClass to check if a class was already added.

Try this:

```
$(this).find("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").filter(function(){
    return !$(this).hasClass('IE8Border');
}).addClass('IE8Border');
```

You can also avoid using filter with the following version:

```
$(this).find("input[type='radio']:not(.IE8Border),input[type='checkbox']:not(.IE8Border)").addClass('IE8Border');
```

**EDIT:** 
If your check is just for existence of a class then try this:

```
$(this).find("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").filter(function(){
  var thisClass = $(this).attr("class");
    return !(thisClass && thisClass.length > 0);
}).addClass('IE8Border');
```

Comment: @Cybernate: But what, if you don't know the class and just want to know: `if(already has some class)`? I think that is the question here.

Comment: @Marnix: I totally missed that. Updated the post with that option.

Comment: @Cybernate: You could also do `$("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").not('.IE8Border').addClass('IE8Border');`

Comment: @Cybernate: Nah I'm fine, you were faster. Still, your edit seems to be the best post for as far as the question reaches.

Comment: @Cybernate: I read even more in the question. He also asks: I want to overwrite the old class.

Comment: @Marnix: Yes I saw that. But overwrite looks little vauge. @Naga: Can you pls elaborate on the "overwrite" part?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little unclear on what you're asking, so I have two answers for you:

If you are trying to avoid adding duplicate classes (i.e. adding `IE8Border` twice), you don't need to filter anything. `.addClass()` will only add the class if it doesn't already exist on the element.

If you want to add a class to only those elements that don't already have a class, try this:

```
$(this).find("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").filter(function() {
   return this.className === '';
}).addClass('IE8Border');
```

[Have a look at this demo to see this working ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/JXG4b/)

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree on Cybernate's answer. But do you just want to add a class or do you want to overwrite? For the latter one try:

```
$("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']",this).filter(function(){
    var thisClass = $(this).attr("class");
    return !(thisClass && thisClass.length > 0);
}).removeAttr('class').addClass('IE8Border');
```

and to extend of Cybernate's answer, instead of `filter()`, you can also use the `not()` function.

```
$("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").not('.IE8Border').addClass('IE8­Border');
```